# OpenAI completion got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, openai-api

I'm trying to create a python telegram bot which will generate text with openai. but when i'm trying to put openai function into code - it says "OpenAIObject.to_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'"

`

```
ONE = openai.Completion.create(engine="text-davinci-002",
    prompt="say hi to user",
    temperature=0.7,
    max_tokens=20,)
TWO = 'Skip'

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:

    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Generate", callback_data=ONE),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Skip", callback_data=TWO),
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    await update.message.reply_text("Select an action", reply_markup=reply_markup)


async def button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:

    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    await query.edit_message_text(text=f"Selected option: {query.data}")


app = ApplicationBuilder().token("5666054268:AAEioS6Vd1q7_Nu-AvBVnHS4UoXUtnwramg").build()

app.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
app.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))

app.run_polling()
```

`